# Vue route guards to differentiate between page reload (e.g. F5/browser clicked refresh button) and directly pasting URL

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Just want to check if it's possible to differentiate the above purely with route guards.

What I need to achieve:

My form has 4 stages. It should progress in sequence (A->B->C->D)

1. As a logged in user, if I came from /urlA and I'm on /urlB. Then when I refresh the browser, I should stay on /urlB.
2. As a logged in user, if I try to access /urlB directly by pasting the url into the address bar without coming "from" /urlA, then I want to redirect user to /urlA

Problem is in the global route/navigation guards (beforeEach), the "from" is always null for both #1 and #2.

Is it possible to differentiate #1 & #2 from Vue's route/nav guards? Alternatively, I need to go down the path of setting some kind of flag in store, mapState.. etc. If the guards can do it, it seems to be a cleaner/more elegant solution.

```
if (to.name === ROUTES.A && from.name !== ROUTES.B) {
 //from is always null when I do a browser refresh or paste url directly
 next({
  replace: true,
  name: ROUTES.A,
  params: {
    id: to.params.id
  }
})
```

}

Comment: As far as your client-side code is concerned, there is no difference between a page reload and direct URL access

Comment: @Phil, ouch. Got it. If anyone has a cleaner, more elegant way of doing this, do share! Thanks in advance, SO!